# My script works ie script tool but it doesn't work sharepoint script editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I am creating a dynamic table and retrieve my custom list when I press the button it is okay. After than when I double click to any column I want to edit it. 
I wrote a basic jQuery script:

```
    $("td").dblclick(function () {
    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
    alert(OriginalContent);
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var newContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        }
    });

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
});
});
```

it works on IE script tool but when I copy and paste to Sharepoint script editor it doesn't work. I can't understand why. Why doesn't it work? How should I use it or what can I do?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: no, it is working correctly on console